# Openshift node.js mongodb process.nextTick throw error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

It seems the server can't connect to the mongodb. But I am using openshift's recommend process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL and I have consoloe.log this env. And it's correct. I am sure the mongodb service is running, cause mongo works. I am confused. What's wrong?

`var mongodb_connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + 'test';
mongoose.connect(mongodb_connection_string);`